# Scroll canvas horizontally

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to plot an "infinite" graph, the idea is that I will redraw the canvas into itself, by moving it one pixel left, and then clear the rightmost column, drawing a pixel into a cleared column. But something doesn't work, and I cannot understand what. The example code below:

```
var telemetryScreen, telemetryTimer;

function displayUI() {
    if (!telemetryScreen) {
        telemetryScreen = document.createElement("div");
        telemetryScreen.className = "telemetry-screen";
        document.body.appendChild(telemetryScreen);
    }
    return telemetryScreen;
}

var plotFps = function(canvas) {
    canvas.className = "telemetry-fps";
    canvas.width = 320;
    canvas.height = 240;
    canvas.getContext("2d").fillStyle = "red";
    if (!telemetryScreen) displayUI().appendChild(canvas);
    return function (delta) {
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.drawImage(canvas, 1, 0, 319, 240, 0, 0, 319, 240);
        context.clearRect(319, 0, 1, 240);
        context.fillRect(319, 120 + delta, 1, 1);
    };
}(document.createElement("canvas"));

function startSampling() {
    var now, delta, last, start = new Date().getTime(),
    seconsPerFrame = 16;
    if (telemetryTimer) clearInterval(telemetryTimer);
    telemetryTimer = setInterval(
        function () {
            last = now;
            now = new Date().getTime();
            delta = now - last - seconsPerFrame;
            plotFps(delta);
        }, seconsPerFrame);
    // We don't anticipate framerates
    // higher then 60 fps
}

startSampling();
```

I've also tried `translate()`, but it stops working after the canvas would scroll more then one of its width :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an infinite panning effect:

- Each frame, draw the image(or graph) a few pixel to the left of the previous frame
- Draw a copy of the image (or graph) on the right in the “empty” pixels

Here’s basic code for an image (you could draw your graph instead):

```
    var fps = 60;
    var offsetLeft=0;
    function pan() {

        // increase the left offset
        offsetLeft+=1;
        if(offsetLeft>infiniteImageWidth){ offsetLeft=0; }

        ctx.drawImage(infiniteImage,-offsetLeft,0);
        ctx.drawImage(infiniteImage,infiniteImage.width-offsetLeft,0);

        setTimeout(function() {
            requestAnimFrame(pan);
        }, 1000 / fps);
    }
```

Here’s code (you will need to supply your own image due to stupid CORS security):

You can ignore the “mirror image” effect which was used to create a seamless transition on an image of a mountain landscape.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    // thanks Paul Irish for this RAF fallback shim
    window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) {
      return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
      function(callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
      };
    })();


    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var infiniteImage;
    var infiniteImageWidth;
    var img=document.createElement("img");
    img.onload=function(){

      // use a tempCanvas to create a horizontal mirror image
      // This makes the panning appear seamless when
      // transitioning to a new image on the right
      var tempCanvas=document.createElement("canvas");
      var tempCtx=tempCanvas.getContext("2d");
      tempCanvas.width=img.width*2;
      tempCanvas.height=img.height;
      tempCtx.drawImage(img,0,0);
      tempCtx.save();
      tempCtx.translate(tempCanvas.width,0);
      tempCtx.scale(-1,1);
      tempCtx.drawImage(img,0,0);
      tempCtx.restore();
      infiniteImageWidth=img.width*2;
      infiniteImage=document.createElement("img");
      infiniteImage.onload=function(){
          pan();
      }
      infiniteImage.src=tempCanvas.toDataURL();
    }
    img.src="YourLandscapeImage.jpg";


    var fps = 60;
    var offsetLeft=0;
    function pan() {

        // increase the left offset
        offsetLeft+=1;
        if(offsetLeft>infiniteImageWidth){ offsetLeft=0; }

        ctx.drawImage(infiniteImage,-offsetLeft,0);
        ctx.drawImage(infiniteImage,infiniteImage.width-offsetLeft,0);

        setTimeout(function() {
            requestAnimFrame(pan);
        }, 1000 / fps);
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=500 height=143></canvas><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I solved this differently in the end, but this also seems to work. (I replaced the `clearRect` with `drawRect` which used the background colour.) Still awkward that `clearRect` doesn't seem to do what it's supposed to, however, it doesn't do it consistently across browsers, so it must be something about it's purpose that I don't understand.